# Graphics2D - how do I crop the generated image when rendering

Tags: java, graphics2d, affinetransform

I am rendering to a Graphics2D object in Java. My rendering uses coordinates for an 8-1/2 x 11 image, i.e. a standard sheet of paper (and my units are twips if that is relevant).

I have a case where I want to render a 6-1/2 x 9 image - basically the contents of the page without the margins. The easy solution is just subtract 1440 (1") from every x,y coordinate.

However, is there a way where I can set both a transform and cropping so I set this once upon the Graphics2D creation and then everything is both shifted and anything outside the view is cropped out.

I want the cropping because the Graphics2D object can be for a PostScript or SVG output and therefore items outside the view would be problematic.

thanks - dave

Comment: Have you looked at setting the clip of your Graphics object via `setClip(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shift the origin, use Graphics2D.translate(- left, - top). To limit the extent, that is done when you create the underlying bitmap - anything off the edges is not rendered.